# Check if value already exists on an object javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would to check if an id is already in an object.

I push 4 key/values to an object

```
moviesFavorites.push({
  id: movieId,
  title: movieTitle,
  year: movieYear,
  image: movieImage
});
```

it returns something like that :

```
Array[3]
  0: Object
    id: "1170358"
    image: "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/posters_movies/180744-300.jpg?3"
    title: "The Hobbit The Desolation of Smaug"
    year: "2013"

  1: Object
    id: "1335975"
    image: "http://zapp.trakt.us/images/posters_movies/179050-300.jpg?2"
    title: "47 Ronin"
    year: "2013"
length: 2
```

And I create a for loop to check if the id is already on the object but it didn't work. It returns all the time false. What's wrong ?

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < moviesFavorites.length; i++) {
  var globalObj = moviesFavorites[i];

  console.log(globalObj.id in globalObj);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want

```
console.log("id" in globalObj);
```

With the code you have it would be looking for the key that matches the value of `globalObj.id`

So your code basically evaluates to:

```
console.log("1170358" in globalObj);
console.log("1335975" in globalObj);
```

or if the id property didnt exist on globalObj, and not using strict mode, it would look for a key with name `undefined` as id is undefined

```
console.log("undefined" in globalObj);
```